# Making Formatter in Eclipse behave like Visual Studio

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, formatting

I just cannot read the formatted code (Java) in Eclipse after 5 mins and I want it to format the code like VS does (with c#).

This is a rather common problem but I couldnT find anything better than this [site](http://www.jackyliang.com/jackyresumecoding/2014/4/5/make-eclipse-work-more-like-visual-studio). I imported the xml to my settings but couldnT get it to work as expected, it still formats my code into a staircase.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the formatter you created to your project (in the properties of project: Java Code Style -> Formatter) if it is not using the default formatter. After that, right click on your project and choose "Source -> Format" to format all the java files of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Well my bad.. I should have checked the settings that I had imported via xml.

The most annoying formatting behavior of Eclipse was the line wrappings for me.

**Example** of eclipse-formatted-inhuman-readable code:

```
Intent iDefClickIntent = new Intent(context,
                RandomizeWidgetProvider.class);
        iDefClickIntent.setAction(ACTION_TOGGLE_DEF
                + System.currentTimeMillis());
        iDefClickIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY, sDefinition);
        iDefClickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                iWidgetId);
        PendingIntent piDefClick = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                iWidgetId, iDefClickIntent, 0);
        mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetDefinition,
                piDefClick);
```

Even if you cannot find the whole VS settings to import, to fix this, you can change the formatter settings in

- **Java>Code Style>Formatter**

to disable line wrapping settings for Method Declarations, Function calls and Expressions under

- **LineWrapping tab.**